# Rails self and association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, model, associations

I have a car and user model.

```
User.rb
has_many :cars

Car.rb
belongs_to :user
```

I would like to validate model field in the car model only if its user has `mdk_id` not nil.

This is how I create car model,

```
user = User.where(mdk_id: b["companyid"]).first

car = user.cars.build
```

Then in `Car.rb` model, I would like to validate `model` field.

I tried;

```
  validates :model if self.user.mdk_id != nil
```

But it gives error;

```
undefined method `user' for #<Class:0x007f973a321a58>
```

How can I reference that ?

Comment: "Then in Car.rb model, I would like to validate model field." - what do you want to validate on `model` field, presence? uniqueness? what else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a proc to the if option like this:

```
validates :model, presence: true, if: proc { |car| car.user.mdk_id? }
```

(I assumed you need to validate presence of the field, you can change the validation if you need).

Please, check out the [rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#validation-helpers#using-a-proc-with-if-and-unless) on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like these in Car.rb

```
validate :validate_user, on: [:create, :update]

def validate_user
  if self.user.mdk_id == nil
    #display error message here
    #such as User's mdk_id cannot be null etc.
  end
end
```

Comment: No, it is valid  check http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#custom-methods

Comment: I mean by default it will run on both `create` and `update`. No need to mention it.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a validation like this:

```
validates :model if self.user.mdk_id != nil
```

won't work as `self` here is the class `Car` but the validation would be on an instance of `Car`. Additionally, you need to specify what type of validation you want.

Say, you want the `model` field to have a value (mandatory) whenever a car has a user and user has `mdk_id` set, then you can do it as follows:

```
# car.rb
validates :model, presence: true, if: -> { self.user && self.user.mdk_id.present? }
```